Showing $\sum_{i=1}^k i^{-2}(1-i^{-2})^t\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{t}}$ for large $k$
For large $k$, I observe the following:
$$f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^k i^{-2}(1-i^{-2})^t \approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$

What's the easiest way to show this?
Notebook

Depends on how rigorous you want to be. A very rough way to get this is to note that the function $f(x) = \frac{(1-1/x^2)^t}{x^2} \approx \frac{e^{-t/x^2}}{x^2}$ for large $x$ and replacing the sum with an integral and using this approximation gives us $\int_1^\infty e^{-t/x^2}/x^2 dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4t}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{t})$ which gives you the desired asymptotics at large $t$ since $\text{erf}(t)\to 1$. The tedious part here would be to justify all these approximations and control the error.

There should be one more condition to justify the approximation: $t\gg1$.
Numeric shows that at small t the approximation ($\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt t}$) does not hold. At $t>1, k\gg1$ there is a solution by @K. Grammatikos : $S\sim\frac{\sqrt \pi}2B\big(\frac12;t+1\big)$
.

For: $k>>1$ and $t<<1$ we have:$$\frac{1}{30 k^5}-\frac{1}{6 k^3}+\frac{1}{2 k^2}-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-1$$. For: $k>>1$ and $t>>1$ we have:$$-\frac{1}{6 k^3}+\frac{1}{2 k^2}-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{t}{2 k^4}+\frac{t}{3 k^3}+\sum _{\alpha =0}^t (-1)^{\alpha } \binom{t}{\alpha } \zeta (2+2 \alpha )$$

@MariuszIwaniuk how do you get the first part? Is it series expansion from erf?

Using: $\sum _{\alpha =0}^t \binom{t}{\alpha } \left(-\frac{1}{j^2}\right)^{\alpha }=\left(1-\frac{1}{j^2}\right)^t$ we have: $$\sum _{j=1}^k \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{j^2}\right)^t}{j^2}=\sum _{\alpha =0}^t (-1)^{\alpha } \binom{t}{\alpha } H_k^{(2 (1+\alpha ))}$$

and using MMA code: A = Sum[#, {\[Alpha], 0, t}] & /@      Asymptotic[(-1)^\[Alpha] Binomial[t, \[Alpha]] HarmonicNumber[k,         2 (1 + \[Alpha])], {k, Infinity, 2}] // Simplify // Expand;  Asymptotic[A[[1 ;; 6]], {k, Infinity, 3}] + A[[-1]]

We can use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to approximate the sum; the first two terms read
$$F(t;k)=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^t=\int_1^k\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^t dx +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)^t +...$$
With the substitution $u=1/x^2$ the first term as $k\to\infty$ not only converges but it also approaches a beta integral:
$$F(t,k)\approx\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{k^2}}^1du ~u^{-1/2}(1-u)^t\xrightarrow[]{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}B(1/2,t+1)$$
Since the beta function can be expressed via gamma functions
$$B(1/2,t+1)=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(t+3/2)}$$ we can obtain a term by term asymptotic expansion in powers of $1/t$; in particular we can show using the Stirling approximation that
$$F(t,k)\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{t}}+\mathcal{O}(t^{-3/2}, k^{-2}e^{-t/k^2})$$

Consider $t = 1$. Then you can compute :
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{-2} (1 - i^{-2}) = \zeta(2) - \zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi^4}{90}$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function (see this wikipedia page).
This doesn't agree with the formula you suggest, and one can see on the graph you show there is a discrepancy anyway for small $t$. Even for larger $t$, when $t$ is an integer, you should get an explicit (complicated) formula without a square root of $\pi$.
Where does this formula come from ?

The OP likely seeks the first term in a large $t$ asymptotic expansion

Ooh my bad then, I don't answer to that in any way.

The formula came from a series of heuristic approximations in Mathematica which turn's out to give something that fits data much better than I expected.... So I was looking for a simpler explanation

In the same spirit as @K. Grammatikos, consider the continuous case
$$I_k=\int_1^k\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)^t}{i^2}\,di=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (t+1)}{2\,\Gamma \left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\frac 1 k\,\ _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-t;\frac{3}{2
   };\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\tag 1$$ where
$$ _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-t;\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n-t-1)!}{(2 n+1)\, n!\, (-t-1)!}\frac 1{k^{2n}}$$ decreases very fast.
At the limit
$$J=\int_1^\infty\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)^t}{i^2}\,di=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (t+1)}{2\,\Gamma \left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
Using Stirling approximation for large $t$
$$J=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{t}}\Bigg(1-\frac{3}{8 t}+\frac{25}{128
   t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\Bigg)\tag 2$$
Using $t=\pi$ and $k=100$,

$(1)$ gives $0.438785$ while the exact summation gives $0.429529$
$(2)$ gives $0.450212$

